# Cannot connect to SQL Server via TCP/IP

Tags: sql-server, tcp, sql-server-2000

I can't access my SQL Server on my PC from my laptop.

I already:

1. tried to turn off the firewall. I can ping my PC with my laptop.
2. enabled the TCP/IP protocol in network configuration in the SQL Server properties.
3. verified that the SQL Server service is running. I can access locally with toad.

Here is the environment :

- OS - Windows XP
- DBMS - SQL Server 2000

Thank you,
Regards

Comment: Have a look at the **Related** column in the lower-right corner of this page.  This has been asked many times before.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in same network you should be able to access it via IP address. Can you please let us know a bit more.